# Как узнать уникальность картинки?

Tags: php, jpeg

Здравствуйте.

Мне интересно, имеют ли форматы картинок JPEG / JPG | PNG | GIF какие-то свои уникальные id или тех, к примеру, как торрент файлы.

Или возможно как-то по-другому, может, есть возможность определить уникальность картинки...
Идея вообще-то состоит в том, чтобы не загружать на хостинг картинок те же самые изображения...

Comment: @Юрий Зав, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Так к чему в итоге пришли, если не секрет? Я сейчас решаю похожу задачу. И как называется новоиспеченный хостинг картинок? :)

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотите отсечь полностью идентичные изображения, то можно использовать hash_file.

Если речь о чуть более сложном анализе, то можно получить сигнатуру изображения при помощи imageMagic:

```
identify -verbose image.jpg
```

Для двух картинок (jpg и png) были получены одинаковые сигнатуры, но md5sum выдавал разные результаты.

Для дополнительного чтения:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931/algorithm-to-compare-two-images

http://habrahabr.ru/post/120577/

Answer (score 0):

Может, вам подойдёт [md5_file](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.md5-file.php) (*или [hash_file](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.hash-file.php), а алгоритм подберете сами*)?

Comment: @Deonis: так мы сможем отсечь только изображения, идентичные до байта - один размер, один тип файла

Comment: Это уже неплохо, ИМХО. Я, бывает, несколько раз один и тот же файл загружаю (например, потому что закрыл вкладку и потерял ссылку).